# Multiuser screen session from a shell script

Tags: shell, sh, tmux, gnu-screen

I've looked up every tutorial i've found but none of them really answer my question.
I'm looking for a way to make a script which will :

- Create a screen
- Launch a "nodejs file.js" command in it
- Distach
- Make the screen accessible to every user from the group "devs"

For now here is the shell script I wrote :

```
#!/bin/bash
# Launcher script for js bot

screen -c ./_shared-conf/multi-screen.conf -dmS botScreen
screen -r botScreen
screen -d -m nodejs init_bot.js
```

and in the multi-screen.conf :

```
multiuser on
acladd rackover # adding every user manually as i don't know how to add group
acladd jj
```

Can you help me ? Thanks

Edit : I've been trying with TMUX, so far i've tried this :

```
Again, Alice and Bob ssh into the same server
Alice, as before, creates a new tmux session: tmux new -s alice. tmux will 
implicitly create a new window group
Bob does not join that same session. Instead he starts a new session and 
connects that session to the same window group as Alice’s session: tmux new -s bob -t alice
```

But this doesn't work neither.

Comment: please edit your Q to show errors or other information. What  you have sounds reasonable, so tell us where it is failing ;-). Good luck.

Comment: I have no errors on firing my shell script, but it simply creates a new screen in which nothing have happened.

Comment: `tmux` allows sharing windows between sessions, but only if the sessions are managed by the same *server*. See the `-S` and `-L` options, and https://www.howtoforge.com/sharing-terminal-sessions-with-tmux-and-screen#sharing-between-two-different-accounts

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that your shell script will only launch the bot after you exit the screen. Let's go over what the commands do.

```
screen -c ./_shared-conf/multi-screen.conf -dmS botScreen
```

This creates a screen with the given config and doesn't attach.

```
screen -r botScreen
```

This attaches to the screen created before *and* thus waits until you exit or detach (Ctrl+A, D) from the screen.

```
screen -d -m nodejs init_bot.js
```

This creates another detached screen that runs the script.

---

The solution is to do it all in one command. To simply run the bot and then terminate the screen after the bot stops, add the nodejs command at the end:

```
screen -c ./_shared-conf/multi-screen.conf -dmS botScreen nodejs init_bot.js
```

If you want the screen to keep running after the bot stops, then you can use the solution from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47279/250283):

```
screen -c ./_shared-conf/multi-screen.conf -dmS botScreen sh -c 'nodejs init_bot.js; exec bash'
```

This will run `sh` in the screen with the bot, then when the bot terminates runs bash to get an interactive shell within the screen.